# Finding 2 matching sub-lists from list of list

Tags: c#, list, sublist

got this little problem in my little C# hobby project that I can't quite work out. I have been stuck in lots of messy and complicated nested loops. Hope someone can give light.

I have a list of list of int, i.e. `List<List<int>>` . Assume each list of int contains unique items. The minimum size of the list is 5. I need to find **exactly two** lists of int (List A and List B) that share **exactly three** common items and another list of int (List X) that contains **exactly one** of these common items. Another condition must hold: none of the other lists contain any of these three items.

For example:

```
List<List<int>> allLists = new List<List<int>>();
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {1, 2});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {3, 4});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {4, 6, 8});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {5, 7, 9, 11});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {6, 7, 8});
```

For the above example, I would hope to find a solution as:

```
ListA and ListB: [3, 5] // indices of allLists
ListX: 6 // index of allLists
The three shared items: [5, 7, 9]
The matching item in ListX: 7
```

Note: Depending on the content of lists, there may be multiple solutions. There may be also situations that no lists is found matching the above conditions.

I was stuck in some messy nested loops. I was thinking if anyone may come up with a simple and efficient solution (possibly with LINQ?)

Originally I had something stupid like the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allLists.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (allLists[i].Count > 2)
    {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < allLists.Count; j++)
        {
            List<int> sharedItems = allLists[i].Intersect(allLists[j]).ToList();
            if (sharedItems.Count == 3)
            {
                foreach (var item in sharedItems)
                {
                    int itemCount = 0;
                    int? possibleListXIndex = null;
                    for (var k = 0; k < allLists.Count; k++)
                    {
                        if (k != i && k != j && allLists[k].Contains(item))
                        {
                            // nested loops getting very ugly here... also not sure what to do....
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Extended Problem**

There is an extended version of this problem in my project. It is in the same fashion:

- find **exactly three** lists of int (List A, List B and List C) that share **exactly four** common items
- find another list of int (List X) that contains **exactly one** of the above common items
- none of the other lists contain these four items.

I was thinking the original algorithm may become scalable to also cover the extended version without having to write another version of algorithm from scratch. With my nested loops above, I think I will have no choice but to add at least two deeper-level loops to cover four items and three lists.

I thank everyone for your contributions in advance! Truly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0) and / or [Enumerable.Exept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0) can help you and reduce the nested loops?

Comment: `if (sharedItems.Count > 2)` should be ==3, no?

Comment: Is `var j = + 1;` a typo/missing an `i` ?  Also, how about intersecting every list with every other and storing the results in a dictionary of intersect members-> lists that intersected thus.. Then you can loop the dictionary keys (intersecting elements) and intersect them back to the main list looking for your single intersect, but only if the count of elements in the value of the dictionary member is the X in the "find exactly X lists of int that share...". (and thus for your dict KeyValuePairs, kvp.Key.Count is the Y in "share exactly Y common items" and value)

Comment: Yes, you are right. typo. should be == 3 and i + 1...

Comment: *Another condition must hold: none of the other lists contain these three items.* - isn't this already implied by the fact that there must be only exactly two of these lists that contain these three items? If another list contained them then there would be 3 lists that contained these 3 items

Comment: Not sure if i get you right... look at list 3 and 4 for [4,6,8]... if i pick list 2 as list x for having item 4. list 0 having item 4 will not pass that condition...

Comment: another counter example: list 3 and 6 [6,7,8]. list x as 5 for item 7. this still won't pass because of list 5 having 6 and 8

Comment: if (k == i || k == j)
       continue;
      var intersected = allLists[k].Intersect(sharedItems).ToList();
      if (intersected.Count == 1)
      {
       Console.WriteLine($"Found index:{k},i:{i},j:{j}, Intersected numbers:{string.Join(",",intersected)}");
      }

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that comes up with your answer.  I wouldn't exactly called it efficient, but it's pretty simple to follow.

It breaks the work in two step.  First it constructs a list of initial candidates where they have exactly three matches.  The second step adds the ListX property and checks to see if the remaining criteria is met.

```
var matches = allLists.Take(allLists.Count - 1)
    .SelectMany((x, xIdx) => allLists
        .Skip(xIdx + 1)
        .Select(y => new { ListA = x, ListB = y, Shared = x.Intersect(y) })
        .Where(y => y.Shared.Count() == 3))
    .SelectMany(x => allLists
        .Where(y => y != x.ListA && y != x.ListB)
        .Select(y => new 
        { 
             x.ListA, 
             x.ListB, 
             x.Shared, 
             ListX = y, 
             SingleShared = x.Shared.Intersect(y) 
        })
        .Where(y => y.SingleShared.Count() == 1 
            && !allLists.Any(z => z != y.ListA 
                && z != y.ListB 
                && z != y.ListX 
                && z.Intersect(y.Shared).Any())));
```

You get the output below after running the following code.

**ListA. 3**: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] **ListB. 5**: [5, 7, 9, 11] => [5, 7, 9], **ListX. 6**:[6, 7, 10] => 7

```
matches.ToList().ForEach(x => {
    Console.WriteLine("ListA. {0}: [{1}] ListB. {2}: [{3}] => [{4}], ListX. {5}:[{6}] => {7}", 
        allLists.IndexOf(x.ListA), 
        string.Join(", ", x.ListA), 
        allLists.IndexOf(x.ListB), 
        string.Join(", ", x.ListB), 
        string.Join(", ", x.Shared),
        allLists.IndexOf(x.ListX),
        string.Join(", ", x.ListX), 
        string.Join(", ", x.SingleShared));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will leave the exercise of further work such as which list matches which other one given your fairly generic requirement.  So here, I find those that match 3 other values in a given array, processing all arrays - so there are duplicates here where an A matches a B and a B matches an A for example.

This should give you something you can work from:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var s = new List<int>();
        List<List<int>> allLists = new List<List<int>>();
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {1, 2, 3, 4});
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {1, 2});
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {3, 4});
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {4, 6, 8});
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {5, 7, 9, 11});
        allLists.Add(new List<int>()
        {6, 7, 8});
        /*
        // To iterate over it.
        foreach (List<int> subList in allLists)
        {
            foreach (int item in subList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
  */
        var countMatch = 3;
        /* iterate over our lists */
        foreach (var sub in allLists)
        {
            /* not the sub list */
            var ns = allLists.Where(g => g != sub);
            Console.WriteLine("Check:{0}", ns.Count()); // 6 of the 7 lists so 6 to check against
            //foreach (var glist in ns) - all of them, now refactor to filter them:
            foreach (var glist in ns.Where(n=> n.Intersect(sub).Count() == countMatch))
            {
                var r = sub.Intersect(glist); // get all the matches of glist and sub
                Console.WriteLine("Matches:{0} in {1}", r.Count(), glist.Count());
                foreach (int item in r)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will output this:

```
Hello World
Check:6
Check:6
Check:6
Check:6
Matches:3 in 3
4
6
8
Matches:3 in 4
5
7
9
Matches:3 in 3
6
7
8
Check:6
Matches:3 in 7
4
6
8
Check:6
Matches:3 in 7
5
7
9
Check:6
Matches:3 in 7
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to break this functionality into several methods, then it will look easier to read.

```
var allLists = new List<List<int>>();
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {1, 2});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {3, 4});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {4, 6, 8});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {5, 7, 9, 11});
allLists.Add(new List<int>() {6, 7, 8});
var count = allLists.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    var left = allLists[i];
    if (left.Count > 2)
    {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
        {
            var right = allLists[j];
            var sharedItems = left.Intersect(right).ToList();
            if (sharedItems.Count == 3)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
                {
                    if (k == i || k == j)
                        continue;
                    var intersected = allLists[k].Intersect(sharedItems).ToList();
                    if (intersected.Count == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Found index k:{k},i:{i},j:{j}, Intersected numbers:{string.Join(",",intersected)}");
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result will be]

Answer (score 0):

I just thought if I try to find the item in List X first, I might need fewer loops in practice. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
        public static void match(List<List<int>> allLists, int numberOfMainListsToExistIn, int numberOfCommonItems)
        {
            var possibilitiesToCheck = allLists.SelectMany(i => i).GroupBy(e => e).Where(e => (e.Count() == numberOfMainListsToExistIn + 1));
            foreach (var pGroup in possibilitiesToCheck)
            {
                int p = pGroup.Key;
                List<int> matchingListIndices = allLists.Select((l, i) => l.Contains(p) ? i : -1).Where(i => i > -1).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < matchingListIndices.Count; i++)
                {
                    int aIndex = matchingListIndices[i];
                    int bIndex = matchingListIndices[(i + 1) % matchingListIndices.Count];
                    int indexOfListXIndex = (i - 1 + matchingListIndices.Count) % matchingListIndices.Count;
                    int xIndex = matchingListIndices[indexOfListXIndex];

                    IEnumerable<int> shared = allLists[aIndex].Intersect(allLists[bIndex]).OrderBy(e => e);
                    IEnumerable<int> xSingle = shared.Intersect(allLists[xIndex]);
                    bool conditionsHold = false;
                    if (shared.Count() == numberOfCommonItems && xSingle.Count() == 1 && xSingle.Contains(p))
                    {
                        conditionsHold = true;
                        for (int j = 2; j < matchingListIndices.Count - 1; j++)
                        {
                            int cIndex = matchingListIndices[(i + j) % matchingListIndices.Count];
                            if (!Enumerable.SequenceEqual(shared, allLists[aIndex].Intersect(allLists[cIndex]).OrderBy(e => e)))
                            {
                                conditionsHold = false;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        if (conditionsHold)
                        {
                            List<int> theOtherListIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, allLists.Count - 1).Except(matchingListIndices).ToList();
                            if (theOtherListIndices.Any(x => shared.Intersect(allLists[x]).Count() > 0))
                            {
                                conditionsHold = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (conditionsHold)
                    {
                        matchingListIndices.RemoveAt(indexOfListXIndex);
                        Console.Write("List A and B: {0}. ", String.Join(", ", matchingListIndices));
                        Console.Write("Common items: {0}. ", String.Join(", ", shared));
                        Console.Write("List X: {0}.", xIndex);
                        Console.WriteLine("Common item in list X: {0}. ", p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

For the above example, I will just call  the method like this:

```
match(allLists, 2, 3);
```

This method will also work with the extended problem:

```
match(allLists, 3, 4);
```

... and even more if the problem is even further more extended to (4, 5) and so on...